# display hide/show particular issue

Tags: html, css, meteor, display

I have this code:

```
'click #StartersButton' : function() {
var secondColumn = document.getElementById("secondColumn");
var thirdColumn = document.getElementById("thirdColumn");

  if($(window).width() < 800 ) {
    secondColumn.style.display = "inline";
    thirdColumn.style.display = "none";
  }
},
'click #ProButton' : function() {
  var secondColumn = document.getElementById("secondColumn");
  var thirdColumn = document.getElementById("thirdColumn");

  if($(window).width() < 800 ) {
    secondColumn.style.display = "none";
    thirdColumn.style.display = "inline";
  }
},
```

and this is the html

```
<div id="mobileVersion">
<ul class="plan_tabs">
  <li><button name="button"  id="StartersButton" type="button">STARTERS</button></li>
  <li><button name="button"  id="ProButton" type="button">PRO</button></li>
</ul>
```

I use this trigger event when it's on mobile version and it works only one issue I have. After the event trigger the elements have the same display property even if I resize the screen like > 800. In my css I have 2 media:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 800px) {
#thirdColumn {
 display: none;
}

#mobileVersion {
 display: flex;
}
}
@media screen and ( min-width: 801px) {
  #mobileVersion{
  display: none;
  }

  #secondColumn{
   display: inline;
  }
  #thirdColumn{
   display: inline;
  }
}
```

The thing is when I trigger the event the display from css is override( inline css override my normal css) and it cannot be changed back even if I change the size of the display.

Comment: hint: inline styles (ex: `secondColumn.style.display`) take precedence over linked file CSS rules (if not considering `!important` keyword). Either use classes instead of inline styles, or clear the inline styles when needed.

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath ! I've tried with if($(window).width() <800){
          $("#secondColumn").addClass("NotShow");
          $("#secondColumn").addClass("JustShow"); but I believe the syntax it's wrong because it doesn't work